# What is the proper way to convert Go func into an uintptr?

Tags: go, pointers, type-conversion, system-calls

I need to pass and receive a Go function from and into Go code.

The type used for "passage" is `uintptr` due to how system calls work in Go language.
I have no other choice other than `uintptr`, because `syscall.SyscallN` accepts and returns this type.

What is the proper way to convert Go `func` into an `uintptr` ?

I tried to play with it in a sandbox, but I can not convert it simply.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var f MyFunc = SumInt
    fmt.Println(f(1, 2))
    test(uintptr(f))                 // Cannot convert an expression of the type 'MyFunc' to the type 'uintptr'
    test(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(f))) // Cannot convert an expression of the type 'MyFunc' to the type 'unsafe.Pointer'
}

type MyFunc func(a int, b int) (sum int)

func SumInt(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func test(x uintptr) {
    var xf MyFunc
    xf = MyFunc(x)                 // Cannot convert an expression of the type 'uintptr' to the type 'MyFunc'
    xf = MyFunc(unsafe.Pointer(x)) // Cannot convert an expression of the type 'unsafe.Pointer' to the type 'MyFunc'
    fmt.Println(xf(1, 2))
}
```

I searched in internet, but this information is not visible in Google directly.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your underlying use case for this sort of thing?

Comment: I am performing a series of experiments to learn the internals of Go language. I decompile the code and analyze it.

Comment: That's a good use case.  Note that functions are represented as a structure of two fields in Go, permitting closures to be implemented.  If you take the pointer to a function, you get the address of this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way !
I need to pass a pointer to function.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var f MyFunc = SumInt
    fmt.Println(f(1, 2))
    test(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&f)))
}

type MyFunc func(a int, b int) (sum int)

func SumInt(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func test(x uintptr) {
    var xfp *MyFunc
    xfp = (*MyFunc)(unsafe.Pointer(x))

    var xf MyFunc
    xf = *xfp
    fmt.Println(xf(1, 2))
}
```

```
3
3

Process finished with the exit code 0
```

Comment: Note that converting an `uintptr` back to an `unsafe.Pointer` is not well-defined according to the [unsafe.Pointer rules](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer).  I recommend storing function pointers of interest in an array and using indices into the array to identify functions instead.  You may also use reflection.